# Displaying a Table in DataGridView (inside of a form)

Tags: winforms, powershell, datagridview

I'm trying to put a `DataGridView` inside of a form. The form and `DataGridView` appear without issue, but the table doesn't seem to be displaying correctly.

Here's the function that creates the table:

```
function tableCreator(){
    $script:statusTable = @()
    $txtPath = $script:targetName
    Get-Content $txtPath | % {
        $script:statusTable += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
            Computer   = "$_";
            Connection = "NA";
            Status     = "NA"
        }
    }
    #$script:statusTableLength = $script:statusTable.Length
}
```

Here's the `DataGridView` object:

```
$script:statusOutput = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView  #creating the text box System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$script:statusOutput.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(20,100) #location of the text box (px) in relation to the primary window's edges (length, height)
$script:statusOutput.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(600,350) #the size in px of the text box (length, height)
$script:statusOutput.ScrollBars = "Vertical" #adding scroll bars if required
$script:statusOutput.DataSource = $script:statusTable
```

And here's the function that loads the form and sets the `DataSource` to the table:

```
function runstatusFormFunc {
    $reviewprocessForm.Close()
    $reviewprocessForm.Visible = $false

    tableCreator
    testConnection
    $script:statusOutput.DataSource = $script:statusTable
    $runstatusForm.Add_Shown({$runstatusForm.Activate()})

    [void] $runstatusForm.ShowDialog()
}
```

The final output looks like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFsNI.png]

Comment: Not a solution to your problem, but some general advice: avoid using global variables wherever possible. Also avoid appending to an array in a loop. And particularly avoid doing both at the same time. Simply output your objects inside the function `tableCreator` and collect them when you invoke the function (`$statusOutput.DataSource = tableCreator`).

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I adhere to this as much as possible, however, I modify the DataGridView and the StatusTable within a separate function so this is not one of those possible scenarios. Although I might add that $Script is not a $Global scope.

Comment: `script:` is script-global (whereas `gobal:` is runtime-global), but it's global nontheless, with all of the negative side effects.

Answer (score 1):

Well my issue was that `DataGridView` doesn't accept an Array as a `DataSource`. It will only accept an ArrayList.

```
$Script:statusTable = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
```

Instead of

```
$Script:statusTable = @()
```

Resolves the issue and DataGridView outputs the object table correctly